# How is/was this guitar vocoder effect achieved?

Tags: recording, production, technique, funk

In *Funkify Your Life* by the Meters (and many other Funk tracks I've heard), the guitar line blends with a vocoder effect. You can hear it in the first 30 seconds [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKnr9sWivsI).

How was this achieved back then and has anything changed with modern recording techniques?

Answer (score 6):

That would be a [Talk Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_box) (the track referenced in your questions is [listed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_box#Notable_Uses) on the Wikipedia page).

The gadget works by having a small loudspeaker linked by plastic tube to the musician's mouth, allowing the shaping of notes with the mouth, much as a singer would.

There is a nice clip on YouTube of [Peter Frampton using such a device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROtFteYkvoU).

Comment: I can't remember exactly who it was (hence this being a comment),but I seem to recall someone saying they were going to stop using such a gadget because it vibrated their teeth loose!